# What is the equvalent of TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS in django2

Tags: python, django

Hello I'am migrating a project from Django 1.9.12 to Django2.0
I haven't write it it was left behind from a collegue that doesnt work any more in our enterprise

after installing Django2

```
from django.conf.global_settings import  TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCCESSORS
```

returns error

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS'
```

what is the equivalent of `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCCESSORS` in django2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove this line from your settings:

```
from django.conf.global_settings import TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS
```

was deprecated in Django 1.8 and removed in Django 1.10. It's not possible to import it anymore.

You have already defined `context_processors` in your `TEMPLATES` setting, so you don't need `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` anymore

Answer (score 1):

There were removed in [django-1.10](/questions/tagged/django-1.10), like the [release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/1.10/#features-removed-in-1-10) specify:

> The following settings are removed, and you **must upgrade to the
>   `TEMPLATES`** setting:
>
> ```
> ALLOWED_INCLUDE_ROOTS
> TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS
> TEMPLATE_DEBUG
> TEMPLATE_DIRS
> TEMPLATE_LOADERS
> TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID
> ```

So those are in the `TEMPLATES` setting under the `OPTIONS` and then `context_processors`. Since there can be *multiple* `TEMPLATES`, there can be multiple such templates. The `TEMPLATES` in the `global_settings` is however an *empty* list:

```
>>> from django.conf.global_settings import  TEMPLATES
>>> TEMPLATES
[]
```